# ASP.NET Web API ensure compatible versions behind load balancer

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, load-balancing

I have an ASP.NET Core WebAPI app that runs in on-prem environment and I'm trying to scale-out the application. The app is deployed on multiple web servers and set behind a load balancer. All application instances within NLB cluster are connected to same database.

I already did most of problematic aspects, including distributed caching and distributed background job scheduler. The app is periodically updated and newer versions may introduce changes that may be incompatible between simultaneously running instance versions (for example, EF migrations) so I'm looking for approaches I should research.

One (obvious) idea is to store a value of minimum supported version in a database shared across app instances. The flow would look this way:

1. node A starts and checks if its version equals or higher than minimum supported. Assume its version equals, the app continues to run.
2. node B starts and checks if its version equals or higher than minimum supported. Assume it's not. The app throws a terminating exception and exits (or runs in a zombie mode, do not respond to any requests, including heartbeat)
3. node C starts and checks if its version equals or higher than minimum supported. Assume it is higher. Since node C is newer than any other, it will overwrite minimum supported version in DB.
4. every node periodically checks its version against minimum supported value in DB to ensure it is still compatible with other running nodes and stops when it's not anymore.

Wondering if this approach is good enough for this task or there are better ways?

Answer (score -1):

Your approach of storing the minimum supported version in a shared database is a valid approach to confirm compatibility between simultaneously running instance versions. This approach allows you to handle situations where a newer version is introduced.

While choosing any approach  It's important to consider factors such as downtime tolerance, user experience, and the complexity of managing compatibility between different versions.

as a different approach you can consider using a DevOps or other management tool that can be beneficial in ensuring compatible versions behind a load balancer. These tools provide a centralized platform for managing your application deployments, infrastructure, and configuration, making it easier to maintain consistency across multiple instances.

Dev ops can help Automated Deployment,Configuration Management,Infrastructure as Code,Rollback and Rollforward,Monitoring and Alerting,Testing and Validation.

Using a DevOps or management tool can streamline your deployment processes, improve consistency, and provide better control over the compatibility of different versions behind the load balancer. It's important to choose a tool that aligns with your specific requirements and integrates well with your existing infrastructure and workflows.

update:

Below are some other approaches you can consider:

1. Graceful Shutdown: Instead of throwing a terminating exception and exiting, you can implement a graceful shutdown where the node stops accepting new requests but continues to serve existing or ongoing requests until they are completed. This can help avoid termination and provide a better user experience.
2. Feature Flags: Another approach is to use feature flags or feature toggles to control the availability of new features introduced in newer versions. This allows you to enable or disable specific features based on the version of the running instance. Feature flags provide more granular control over the availability of features and can help mitigate compatibility issues between different versions.
3. Blue-Green Deployment: Consider implementing a blue-green deployment strategy where you have two identical environments (blue and green). You can update one environment at a time, ensuring compatibility and testing before switching traffic to the updated environment. This approach provides a seamless transition between versions and allows you to roll back easily if any issues arise.

Comment: DevOps is not an option, because applications are deployed in on-prem environments with no dev infrastructure and potentially disconnected from internet. Apps deployed in a Windows Installer form.

Comment: @Crypt32 i have updated the answer you can consider other ways which is mentioned in the post